# cut a path from DAG that has minimal conductance

Tags: algorithms, combinatorial-optimization, np

Given a directed acyclic graph $G=(V,E)$, a source node $s$ and a sink node $t$, we want to find a path $P$ from $s$ to $t$ such that if we separate all the nodes in $V$ to two parts $P$ (all the nodes in the path) and $S=V\setminus P$,the conductance $|E_{P,S}|/|E_{P}|$ is minimal. Here $E_{P}=\{(u,v)\in E|u,v\in P\}$ and $E_{P,S}=\{(u,v)\in E|u\in P,v\in S \quad\text{or}\quad u\in S,v\in P\}$.

I know that in general minimal conductance cut is an NP-hard problem, but I don't know if this one is also NP-hard. Does this problem have a polynomial solution?

Thanks!